# Html does not load css

Tags: html, css

The problem is that the specified css file is not loading with the html. When I open the html file in a browser there is no change to the style. All files are on my computer.

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" herf="hello.css">
</head>

<body>
    <a href="settings.html">Settings</a>
</body>
</html>
```

hello.css (same directory):

```
body {
width: 1000px;
height: 1000px;
background: red !important;
}
```

The output: 
[image: a busy cat]
(or: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlR7a.png)

Comment: you put herf instead of href : href="hello.css"

Comment: True. Silly me, it was driving me crazy...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo. 

Answer (score 4):

In your **link** tag inside head section, please modify **herf** tag as **href**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hello.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Please explain down-votes! This answer appears to be correct.